# Can “A fall into the(a) pit, a gain in your wit” mean "learning from mistakes"?

Tags: meaning

“A fall into the(a) pit, a gain in your wit” was translated from a famous Chinese proverb that means "learning from mistakes".

From a native English speaker's perspective, can such a translation retain its original meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Learning from one's mistakes** could be a precis of the proverb. The translation in [this blog](https://nagaap.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/a-fall-into-the-pit-a-gain-in-your-wit/) is rather more expansive.

> *A fall into the pit, a gain in your wit.*
>
> > This proverb’s message is: Having gone through a setback, one will have gained experience and wisdom, which will be useful if only one can take warning and learn something from the setback.

Comment: Since English is not my mother tongue, I wonder how a native English speaker will understand this translation the first time he/she see it.

Comment: I understood it well enough, and English is my native language. "Learning from one's mistakes" is probably a better way of expressing it in Plain English, but there is a subtlety in the expanded translation that I rather like.